# Получить последнее сообщение Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel, api

Доброго времени суток!

Есть 3 таблицы

conversations

messages

user_conversation

Делаю чат!

Хочу получить все диалоги с пользователями.

Делают вот такой запрос

```
public function getAll($request)
{
    $conversations = Conversation::with(['messages', 'users' => function ($query) {
        $query
            ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.avatar')
            ->where('users.id', '!=', auth()->user()->id);
    }])
        ->select(['conversations.id', 'conversations.title', 'conversations.last_message_at'])

        ->whereHasUser(auth()->user()->id)
        ->orderByDesc('conversations.last_message_at')
        ->get();

    return $conversations;
}
```

Получаю:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": null,
        "last_message_at": "2019-04-22 09:52:36",
        "messages": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": 1,
                "messageable_id": 3,
                "messageable_type": "App\\Models\\Conversation",
                "text": "Привет",
                "status": "unread",
                "created_at": "2019-04-19 14:39:45",
                "updated_at": "2019-04-19 14:39:45"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "user_id": 1,
                "messageable_id": 3,
                "messageable_type": "App\\Models\\Conversation",
                "text": "Привет еще раз",
                "status": "unread",
                "created_at": "2019-04-22 09:36:49",
                "updated_at": "2019-04-22 09:36:49"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "user_id": 2,
                "messageable_id": 3,
                "messageable_type": "App\\Models\\Conversation",
                "text": "Привет Богдан",
                "status": "unread",
                "created_at": "2019-04-22 09:52:36",
                "updated_at": "2019-04-22 09:52:36"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Сергей",
                "avatar": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": null,
        "last_message_at": "2019-04-19 14:39:50",
        "messages": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 1,
                "messageable_id": 4,
                "messageable_type": "App\\Models\\Conversation",
                "text": "Привет",
                "status": "unread",
                "created_at": "2019-04-19 14:39:50",
                "updated_at": "2019-04-19 14:39:50"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "2koi5KFJoa",
                "avatar": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Новый групповой чат",
        "last_message_at": "2019-04-19 12:36:46",
        "messages": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "messageable_id": 1,
                "messageable_type": "App\\Models\\Conversation",
                "text": "Привет Всем!",
                "status": "unread",
                "created_at": "2019-04-19 12:36:46",
                "updated_at": "2019-04-19 12:36:46"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Сергей",
                "avatar": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "2koi5KFJoa",
                "avatar": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Как я могу получить только последнее сообщения , а не все сразу?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного модифицируй метод получения результатов:

```
    $conversations = Conversation::with([
        'messages' => function($query){
            $query->orderByDesc('created_at')->limit(1);
        }, 
        'users' => function ($query) {
            $query
                ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.avatar')
                ->where('users.id', '!=', auth()->user()->id);
    }])
        ->select(['conversations.id', 'conversations.title', 'conversations.last_message_at'])

        ->whereHasUser(auth()->user()->id)
        ->orderByDesc('conversations.last_message_at')
        ->get();

    return $conversations;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать сортировку по последней дате и брать нужную запись

```
...->orderBy('last_message_at', 'desc')->first();
```